# How to use multidimensional array in mysql query with php?

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I am using three tables and one query in mysql in order to retrieve a particular user.

I am getting exactly what I want from the query, but it's not formatted in the right way.

My query:

```
 public function get_all_payslips()
                {
                    $empid = $this->session->userdata('EMPLOYEE_ID');
                    $orgid = $this->session->userdata('CURRENT_ORG_ID');                    
                    $where = "EMPLOYEE_ID ='".$empid."' ";
                    $response = array();
                    $queryString = "SELECT
                                    em.EMPLOYEE_ID,
                                    em.EMPLOYEE_NAME
                                    FROM                                   
                                    uk_new_salary_slip assd,
                                    employee_master em
                                    WHERE
                                    em.".$where."
                                    GROUP BY em.EMPLOYEE_ID
                                    order by em.EMPLOYEE_NAME asc";                            
                    $query = $this->db->query($queryString);

                    foreach ($query->result() as $data) 
                    {         
                        $result = array();
                        $result['EMPLOYEE_NAME'] = $data-> EMPLOYEE_NAME;
                        $queryString = "SELECT
                                    mo.months,
                                    MONTH((assd.pay_period)) as monthss,
                                    YEAR((assd.pay_period)) as PAY_YEAR,
                                    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(assd.id)) as action,
                                    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(assd.ORG_ID)) as org
                                    FROM                         
                                    uk_new_salary_slip assd,
                                    employee_master em,                               
                                    months mo
                                    WHERE
                                    assd.emp_id =  ". $data->EMPLOYEE_ID ."
                                      AND mo.id =  MONTH((assd.pay_period))
                                      GROUP BY monthss,PAY_YEAR
                                      order by PAY_YEAR desc";
                        $queryString1 = "SELECT
                                    mo.months,
                                    MONTH((germany.pay_from)) as monthss,
                                    YEAR((germany.pay_from)) as PAY_YEAR,
                                    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(germany.id)) as action,
                                    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(germany.ORG_ID)) as org
                                    FROM                         
                                    new_germany_salary_slip germany,
                                    employee_master em,                               
                                    months mo
                                    WHERE
                                    germany.emp_id =  ". $data->EMPLOYEE_ID ."
                                      AND mo.id =  MONTH((germany.pay_from))
                                      GROUP BY monthss,PAY_YEAR
                                      order by PAY_YEAR desc";
                        $queryString2 = "SELECT
                                    mo.months,
                                    MONTH((poland.pay_from)) as monthss,
                                    YEAR((poland.pay_from)) as PAY_YEAR,
                                    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(poland.id)) as action,
                                    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(poland.ORG_ID)) as org
                                    FROM                         
                                    new_poland_salary_slip poland,
                                    employee_master em,                               
                                    months mo
                                    WHERE
                                    poland.emp_id =  ". $data->EMPLOYEE_ID ."
                                      AND mo.id =  MONTH((poland.pay_from))
                                      GROUP BY monthss,PAY_YEAR
                                      order by PAY_YEAR desc";

                        $query1 = $this->db->query($queryString);                       
                        $query2 = $this->db->query($queryString1);
                        $query3 = $this->db->query($queryString2);                  


                        $children = array();
                        foreach ($query1->result() as $data1)
                            {
                                $yearArray = array();                          
                                $yearArray['month'] = $data1->months;
                                $yearArray['year'] = $data1->PAY_YEAR;
                                $yearArray['org'] = $data1->org;                            
                                $yearArray['action'] = $data1->action;
                                array_push($children, $yearArray);
                            }
                        foreach ($query2->result() as $data2)
                            {
                                $yearArray = array();                          
                                $yearArray['month'] = $data2->months;
                                $yearArray['year'] = $data2->PAY_YEAR;
                                $yearArray['org'] = $data2->org;                            
                                $yearArray['action'] = $data2->action;
                                array_push($children, $yearArray);
                            }
                        foreach ($query3->result() as $data3)
                            {
                                $yearArray = array();                          
                                $yearArray['month'] = $data3->months;
                                $yearArray['year'] = $data3->PAY_YEAR;
                                $yearArray['org'] = $data3->org;                            
                                $yearArray['action'] = $data3->action;
                                array_push($children, $yearArray);
                            }
                            $result['children'] = $children;
                            array_push($response, $result);

                    }                   
                    return $response;                   
                }
```

If in the `month` array the `year` is same then the IN `action` value should be `4,2` . If you see in object 0th and 4th month and year is the same so both object's `action` values should be in one row, and similarly its `org` value should be `org:40,47` respectively.

```
{month:"FEBRUARY", year:"2018",org:"40,47",action:"4,2"}
```

I want the data to be formatted like this but in my case it shows different rows for each action.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Array push just adds elements on to the end of the array. It is not what you want. You want to essentially compound elements of the same year and month. To do that we can assign that as the 1st sub array key and simply append the array values to `org` and `action`:

```
    $output = array();
    foreach ($query1->result() as $data1) {
        $key = $data1->PAY_YEAR . $data1->months;
        if (!isset($output[$key]['month'])) {
            $output[$key]['month'] = $data1->months;
            $output[$key]['year'] = $data1->PAY_YEAR;
        }
        $output[$key]['org'][] = $data1->org;
        $output[$key]['action'][] = $data1->action;
    }
    foreach ($query2->result() as $data2) {
        $key = $data2->PAY_YEAR . $data2->months;
        if (!isset($output[$key]['month'])) {
            $output[$key]['month'] = $data2->months;
            $output[$key]['year'] = $data2->PAY_YEAR;
        }
        $output[$key]['org'][] = $data2->org;
        $output[$key]['action'][] = $data2->action;
    }
    foreach ($query3->result() as $data3) {
        $key = $data3->PAY_YEAR . $data3->months;
        if (!isset($output[$key]['month'])) {
            $output[$key]['month'] = $data3->months;
            $output[$key]['year'] = $data3->PAY_YEAR;
        }
        $output[$key]['org'][] = $data3->org;
        $output[$key]['action'][] = $data3->action;
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(array_keys($output));
```